# Protocol Buffer: How to import?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have 2 .proto files :

**First file:**

```
package com.test.model;

message ProtoModel  {
    required CustomObj custom=1;
}
```

**Second file:**

```
package com.test.model;

message CustomObj {
    required string smth=1;
}
```

The issue here is that "CustomObj"  is said to be "unresolved reference" .
Thus, I've tried to import the second file into first file:

```
import "com/test/model/firstFile.proto"

package com.test.model;    

message ProtoModel  {
    required CustomObj custom=1;
}
```

I still get the same issue !!

Comment: I suspect this is a package-qualifier thing... Try placing both in a package and qualifying the message-name with the package-name

Comment: Actually that what I did ;I put all of them in one file in order to save some time here ... Thx :)

Comment: I've got the following error when I try to add them on one file :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952447/protocol-buffer-enum-issue

Answer (score 6):

The import statement is the folder relative to the place where you invoke `protoc`.
It looks like you have treated it as relative to the package instead.

e.g. if (like me) you store both files in `src/main/resources`, you'd invoke protoc as follows:

```
protoc src/main/resources/firstFile.proto src/main/resources/secondFile.proto --java_out=src/generated/java
```

and your import statement would be `import "src/main/resources/firstFile.proto"`

If you want to store the files in subfolders according to package name, then you just add this accordingly, after the top-level foldername.

HTH

Comment: Actually that what I did ;I put all of them in one file in order to save some time here ... Thx :)

Comment: I've got the following error when I try to add them on one file :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952447/protocol-buffer-enum-issue