# Protocol Buffer: Enum issue

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have the following .proto file :

```
enum Enum1{
    X=0;
    Y=1;    
}
message SomeClass{
    required  Enum1 enum1=1;
    required Enum2 enum2=2;
}
enum Enum2{
    X=0;
    Z=1;    
}
```

When I try to comile it using protoc , I get the following error :

> proto.proto:19:5: "X" is already defined  proto.proto:19:5: Note that
>   enum values use C++ scoping rules, meaning that enum values are
>   siblings of their type, not children of it.  Therefore, "X" must be
>   unique  , not just within "Enum2".

I there any way I could overcome this issue !

Comment: You mean rename X @ Enum2 !! if ys , I cann't right now as there dependency over it on the application,

Comment: You have two same enum instances, X.

Answer (score 39):

You could include your enum inside another message so the visibility will not conflict.

Exemple :

```
message Enum1{
 enum Enum{
     X=0;
     Y=1;    
 }
}

message Enum2{
 enum Enum{
     X=0;
     Y=1;    
 }
}

message SomeClass{
    required  Enum1.Enum enum1=1;
    required Enum2.Enum enum2=0;
}
```

You could also prefix your enum value with something. If you don't change the number after the name of your value, it should stay compatible with your old version :
ex:

```
enum Enum1{
    E1_X=0;
    E1_Y=1;    
}
enum Enum2{
    E2_X=0;
    E2_Z=1;    
}
message SomeClass{
    required  Enum1 enum1=1;
    required Enum2 enum2=2;
}
```

Comment: required is removed from proto3

Comment: This question is 8 years old. It would work with proto3 if used without required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use prefix in enumeration then

```
enum Enum1{
    E1_X=0;
    E1_Y=1;    
}
message SomeClass{
    required Enum1 enum1=1;
    required Enum2 enum2=2;
}
enum Enum2{
    E2_X=0;
    E2_Z=1;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
message SomeClass{
required  Enum1 enum1=1;
required Enum2 enum2=2; }
```

i think you should have something like

```
message SomeClass{
    required  Enum1 enum1.Y;
    required Enum2 enum2.Z;
}
```

edit: you tagged this as Java, but in the question you refer to c++, witch one it is?

edit2: 
After googling a bit I found this http://www.mail-archive.com/protobuf@googlegroups.com/msg04986.html

you need to rename enum1.X or enum2.x to some other name so that they don't conflict.

```
enum Enum1{
    W=0;
    Y=1;    
}
message SomeClass{
    required  Enum1 enum1=1;
    required Enum2 enum2=0;
}
enum Enum2{
    X=0;
    Z=1;    
}
```

if you really cant because of application dependencies i guess you need to redesign your program somehow..

Comment: I use Java but when I compile my .proto file using the protoc compiler , I get the error I mentioned .

Comment: But in this way u mentioned , Enum1 will always have the value of enum1.Y .... is there other suggestions !!