# Different enums, same value in protobuf

Tags: kotlin, protocol-buffers

I have protocol buffer definitions like this:

```
package com.asd;

enum AType {
    A1 = 0;
    A2 = 1;
    Unknown = 2;
}

enum BType {
    B1 = 0;
    B2 = 1;
    Unknown = 2;
}
```

While compiling, I am getting this error:

> "Unknown" is already defined in "com.asd". Note that enum values use
> C++ scoping rules, meaning that enum values are siblings of their
> type, not children of it.  Therefore, "Other" must be unique within
> "com.asd", not just within "BType".

Is there a workaround for this problem other than using different packages?

Comment: You can always rename them `A_Unknown` and `B_Unknown`.

Comment: Yep, that's a good idea if I would design a system from scratch but I am moving an existing system to gGRPC, and those enum values have already defined years ago.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13824703/5923139) help?

Comment: @Aplet123 yes, it helps. I believe there is no direct way of doing this. So, that seems like a good workaround.

Answer (score 14):

I believe there is no straightforward way of using the same enum value in the same package but there are two workarounds ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13824703/6900838)):

1. Use prefix:

   ```
    package com.asd;

    enum AType {
        AType_A1 = 0;
        AType_A2 = 1;
        AType_Unknown = 2;
    }

    enum BType {
        BType_B1 = 0;
        BType_B2 = 1;
        BType_Unknown = 2;
    }
   ```
2. Put the enums in different messages:

   ```
    message ATypeMessage{
        enum AType{
            A1 = 0;
            A2 = 1;
            Unknown = 2;
        }
    }

    message BTypeMessage{
        enum BType{
            B1 = 0;
            B2 = 1;
            Unknown = 2;   
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment, and my suggestion is a hack that might not even work. But have you tried to add the
`option allow_alias = true;`
in both `enum` and use the same value.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#enum

Comment: `allow_alias` only allows you to have different enum constants pointing to the same value within an enum, it won't allow you to set same enum constant names across different enums