# C# protobuf-net serialized object to java

Tags: c#, java, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

So I have a small problem:

A message is sent using MQTT, it consists of a series of serialized objects using protobuf-net in C# (**I can't modify this code**, but I have access to the source). At the other end i receive the serialized objects in Java, the problem is I can't seem to be able to deserialize the objects using protobuf, if anyone ever had this problem and solved it, please help :)

Example of object from C#:

```
using ProtoBuf;

namespace Concentrator.Services
{
[ProtoContract]
public class MeterID
{
    private byte[] _id;

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public byte[] ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value.Length == 16 ? value : null; }
    }

    [ProtoMember(2)] public string MeterType;
}
}
```

My attempt at recreating the same object in Java (the .proto file):

```
syntax = "proto2";

 package mqtt.entity;

 option java_package = "mqtt.entity";
 option java_outer_classname = "ProtoMeter";
 message Meter {
    optional bytes ID = 1;
     optional string MeterType = 2;
  }

  message MeterID {
     repeated Meter mid = 1;
 }
```

A solution to this example would be a huge help, Thanks a lot.

The code where the object is deserialized in C#:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(data, 7, data.Length - 9)
var res = Serializer.Deserialize<List<MeterID>>(ms);
```

this works in C#, I'm trying to achieve the same thing in java

Comment: You say "I can't seem to be able to deserialize the objects", but what happens when you try? Compilation errors? Runtime errors? Data corruption?

Comment: Verify error when trying to deserialize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message in your C# code matches just:

```
message MeterID {
    optional bytes ID = 1;
    optional string MeterType = 2;
}
```

There is no need for a 2-level model (unless you're using `*WithLengthPrefix` in the C# code).  You can also get that output by using:

```
var proto = Serializer.GetProto<MeterID>();
```

---

With your edit, a `List<MeterID>` could be mapped as

```
message List_MeterID {
    repeated MeterID items = 1;
}
```

to be used *in combination with* the previous `MeterID` fragment. Which is what you have in the question. So it comes down to "what currently happens?".

Comment: I'm trying to deserialize in java, the objects comes in a list, I'll update the first post to add the code where they are deserialized in C#

Comment: @cdanisor you didn't mention the `List<T>` :p With that, the .proto from your original question is fine. So that then prompts the question - what happens now? what doesn't work? do you get an exception...? or...?

Comment: There is another problem now :)                     
Exception in thread "MQTT Client Callback" java.lang.VerifyError: class mqtt.entity.ProtoMeter$MeterID overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
The class generated by protoc seems to be bugged, it overrides a final method.

Comment: @cdanisor first check you have the current build of the google protobuf (not protobuf-net) package; if `protoc` still emits illegal java, then I would suggest to report it on the [protobuf list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/protobuf) or on the protobuf (not protobuf-net) [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/list)

Comment: You were right, I used a wrong version of protoc, different from the jar, it works flawlessly now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Cosmin, i am trying to achieve the same thing, trying to de-serialize the .bin file created in C# to object in JAVA.How have you achieved ?

Comment: @Aada it should *just work*. What problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

try regenerate proto-file by `GetProto<T>`

Comment: Be more specific please I never used protobuf before

Comment: `var res = Serializer.GetProto<List<MeterID>>;` and use `res`

Comment: Ok getting that in C# it's a good step but how do I export it in java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947277/protocol-buffer-how-to-import https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto

Comment: GetProto method is great, because this was the simplest example other objects are way bigger and this makes my life a lot easier

Comment: @cdanisor the re-implementation of `GetProto<T>` is relatively recent compared to most of the code - I think it handles most scenarios, but if you get any problems with it, let me know